# classicthesis roman pagenumbering in frontmatter

Tags: page-numbering, classicthesis

i need some help to fix the classicthesis template.
Somehow my Template is not showing the roman numbering on all frontmatter pages. While on the Table of contents the second page is the only page showing the roman numbering. Below is an example of the behavior. I am using this overleaf template https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fra-uas-frankfurt-university-of-applied-sciences-thesis-template/vgjmhzsnwbvj. I want the roman numbering to be shown on all frontmatter pages except for the title page. How can I achieve this?

I am thankful for any help.

[image: First ToC page]

[image: Second ToC page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is quite usual that the first page of chapters or sections like the table of contents are different regarding headers and footers. What you show seems like a feature, not a bug. Is there any need to change it?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Well normally we should include roman numbering for every content page which is part of the frontmatter. To be honest I am not sure if that is a MUST requirement for every thesis at our institution so i will just ask my Examiner about this specific point. Anyways i was trying to get the roman numbering on every frontmatter page which is not empty but i failed to do so.

Comment: This is because you have `\pagestyle{plain}` set. Try `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`. Btw: you may want to ask if roman numbers are allowed at all.